# I changed a single file in a git repo which no one else changed but when I do a push it complains -- why?

Tags: git, git-bash

The error message shown is "updates were rejected because the remote repo contains work you do not have." I would have thought if the specific file had not been changed by someone else that the push of that one file would succeed -- why does Git work this way?

I guess central to the question is whether I am understanding what is happening -- whether Git really works as I understand it which is a change to *any* file in the repo prevent the user from pushing a commit even if the files in the commit were not changed also by another user. That is to me the surprising part since it seems like could work just as well (even better) if a push were rejected only if changes had been made (by another user or users) to the files in the commit.

Answer (score 3):

Your title says `which no one else changed`, but the likely scenario here is that in fact someone else has pushed new commits to the remote branch on which you are currently working.  The typical way to resolve this is to just do a `git pull`:

```
# from your branch
git pull origin your_branch
```

This will bring in the changes from the remote.  After resolving any possible merge conflicts, you may commit your work, and then pushing should work.

Comment: yes, new commits but not changes to the specific file; I only changed one file.

Comment: Yes, _you_ changed only one file _locally_, but this does not preclude the possibility that there exists new work on the _remote_ branch done by someone else.

Comment: right but why not allow the file I changed to be pushed?

Comment: First of all, in Git, you don't push a single file, you push an entire _commit_.  Git is blocking you from pushing this commit, because others have also made commits to the remote branch.  You need to integrate with these changes first.

Comment: my understanding is, i change one file, i git add that one file, i commit and then push. while my local repo is not up-to-date, the single file i changed is correct: it is not missing a change someone else made to it that needs to be merged with my change. I guess my question is, could git work the way I imagined without breaking something?

Comment: @releseabe As already indicated, that isn't the way it works.  Your local repo is a commit behind the remote repo.  Only developers of git itself will be able to answer why git is coded this way, so your last question(of why git is coded this way) is off topic since any answers would be speculative.

Answer (score 2):

Note: [Git thinks in project tree snapshots not individual file revisions.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F)

If you have modified file `A` locally (eg. on `master`) and someone else has modified file `B` on the upstream (eg. `origin/master`) branch, the history graph will look something like this:

```
         (master, "change file A")
          |
          v
1 -- 2 -- 3
      \
       4
       ^
       |
      (origin/master, "change file B")
```

So, before you can push your changes to the remote, you will have to `git pull` (ie. `fetch` and `merge`) the changes from the upstream branch into you local branch. This will create a new merge commit locally.

```
              (master, "merge origin/master into master")
               |
               v
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 5
      \       /
       4 -----
       ^
       |
      (origin/master, "change file B")
```

Now you will be able to push.

Answer (score 0):

It's just telling you that the status of your local branch is not in sync with the remote you are trying to update. It doesn't matter which files changed, it has to be synced.

You have to run a `git pull` before you push your local changes.

Answer (score 0):

As covered in comments of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63571991/11057988), the reason you can't push to the branch is because your local branch is behind the branch at origin.

Best strategy to work on branches changed by multiple people is to create a feature branch (`feature`) from that branch (`master`) and periodically `pull` changes from the `master` and `merge` changes from `feature` to the `master` either locally or through a PR.

This strategy allows you to have your `feature` branch be out of sync with the `master` and yet merge and push to `master` as long as there are no conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Git is all about commits.  Git isn't really about files, although commits contain files.  Git isn't about branches either, although branch names are very helpful—well, in fact, *necessary*—to help you (and Git) *find* the right commits.  But in the end, Git is about the *commits*.

When you have your Git call up some other Git, using `git fetch`, you have your Git get, from that Git, any commits that they have, that you don't, that your Git needs.  Then you begin working locally:

- You pick out some commit, usually using a name—a branch name like `master`, or a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`, although in the end Git really just needs the commit's hash ID—and switch to it, or use `git merge` to combine it with your latest work, or whatever.
- You do some work, use `git add` to copy new and/or updated files back into Git's *index* AKA *staging area* (we won't go into detail here), and run `git commit`.
- Git packages up the copies of files that are in Git's index to make a new snapshot of every file that Git knows about (which is to say, the files in Git's index).  Git adds your name and email address as appropriate to say that you made the commit, uses your computer's clock to put a date-and-time-stamp on the new commit, and stores the new commit into its big database of "every commit this Git knows about".  This action generates a new unique hash ID for the new commit.
- Git now updates whatever branch name you are using to remember this latest commit's hash ID.

It's important to realize, at this point, that each commit:

- has a unique number (its hash ID), which seems random but isn't: it's actually a checksum of every bit of data inside the commit;
- contains a snapshot of *every* file that Git knows about: this is the commit's data; and
- contains the hash ID of the *previous* commit, which Git calls the *parent* of this commit.

What this means is that if we use single uppercase letters to stand in for commit hash IDs, we can draw the commits in your repository like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit.  Commit `H` contains that snapshot, of *all* files, with your latest update to one file.  But commit `H` also contains your name and email address, and a date-and-time stamp (actually two of these), *and* the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

This means that your current *branch name*—let's assume it's `master`—only needs to hold the hash ID of your new commit.  Let's draw that:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Git (your Git in this case) will find any *earlier* commits by starting from `H`, then working backwards.

Meanwhile, because you started from the same set of commits as the ones in the Git over at `origin`, *their* chain of commits must have recently ended at commit `G`, like this:

```
...--F--G   <-- master
```

Your own Git retains a memory of their Git's latest commit, so we might want to draw your state like this:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G   <-- origin/master
```

Now, the issue here is that while you were doing this, *someone else* connected to the Git on `origin`, got commits up through commit `G` into *their* repository, did the same sort of thing, then made some changes and `git add`-ed the updated files and ran `git commit`.  So *they* got a new commit in *their* repository, with a new unique hash ID, different from your commit `H`.  Let's call this commit `I`.  The *parent* of their new commit `I` is existing commit `G`, the same as the parent of your commit `H`.  Then they ran `git push origin master` and got to `origin` before you could.

So *now* `origin` has this, in *their* repository:

```
...--F--G--I   <-- master
```

You now run `git push`, which has your Git call up their Git, find any new commits you have that they don't that you'd like them to have, and send them over.  This sends them your commit `H`:

```
          H   [your commit]
         /
...--F--G--I   <-- master
```

The last step of your `git push` is for your Git to ask their Git, politely, if it is OK for them to set *their* name `master` to remember your new commit `H`.  **This is not OK!**  The reason it's not OK is that if they do that, they will have:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G--I   <-- ???
```

The commit `I`, that someone else sent them, is no longer findable.  They'll start from your commit `H` and work backwards to commit `G`, then back to commit `F`, and so on.  There is no *name* by which to find commit `I`, so it simply won't be found.

#### What you should do

At this point, you must run `git fetch` again.  This will have your Git call up their Git and get any new commits that they have, that you don't, that you need.  In this case, that's commit `I`.  Your Git will get commit `I` from them, then update your `origin/master`:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   <-- origin/master
```

Now that you have all the commits—yours, including `H`, plus all the shared ones, including `I`—*now* you can combine your work with the work done by whoever made commit `I`.

There are two common ways to do this combining: you can use `git merge`, or you can use `git rebase`.  Some people hold strong opinions on which one must be used, but some of them say that only merge is allowed, and others say only rebase is allowed.  What I'll do here is draw how `git merge` works, but it's up to you whether to join the "rebase, don't merge" camp.

If you now run `git merge` and specify that the other commit that your Git should use is commit `I`—you can do this with `I`'s raw hash ID, or using the name `origin/master`, or any other way that lets Git *find* commit `I`—your Git will now figure out what files in commit `G` are the same in *all three* commits (`G`, `H`, and `I`), and which ones *you changed* and which ones *they changed*.  Since, as you say, you and they changed entirely different files, Git will believe that the merge worked.  (It may not have actually worked: maybe the changes they made are not compatible with the changes you made.  It's up to you to verify this somehow; Git can only do the mechanical part.)

Assuming all is good and you let Git make a new *merge commit*, Git makes this new commit, like this:

```
          H
         / \
...--F--G   J   <-- master
         \ /
          I   <-- origin/master
```

New commit `J` is like any other commit, except for one thing: instead of one parent commit hash ID `H`, it has *two* parent commit hash IDs stored.  The first one is commit `H` as usual, but commit `J` remembers a *second* previous commit too, namely commit `I`.

This means that when Git does its usual thing of working backwards from the *last* commit, it can find *both* commits `H` and `I`.  It will find and show both commits before moving back to earlier commit `G`.

If you now run `git push origin master`, your Git calls up their Git and offers to them the new commits that you have, that they don't.  They might still have `H` from your earlier attempt, or might not.<sup>1</sup>  They definitely don't have `J`, since you just made it.  So your Git sends `J`, and `H` if needed, and now they have all your commits.

Now we get back to the polite request: your Git says to them *Please, if it's OK, set your `master` to point to commit `J` now.*  As long as their `master` still names commit `I`, it will be OK this time.  They will take `J` and make their name `master` name commit `J`.  Commit `J` finds both commits `H` and `I`, so they won't lose `I`.  Then, both commits `H` and `I` find `G`, so they won't lose `G` either, nor any of the earlier commits.

Git calls this property—of being able to find the commit that *was* the end of the branch, after updating the branch name to point to a new commit hash ID—a *fast-forward*.  A plain `git push` operation is allowed if the operation is a fast-forward.  Some other operations can also result in fast-forwards: in particular, `git merge` will check whether a real merge is required, or a fast-forward not-actually-a-merge-at-all operation suffices.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's usually not important whether they still have `H`: if they don't, your Git will just give it to them again.  If commit `H` is extremely large, though, you might have to wait a while for each push, if they've dropped `H`.  Different versions of Git, and Git installations, have different amounts of cleanup they do for earlier failed `git push` operations.

---

#### Summary

Git is all about *commits*.  Branch names just let Git *find* commits.  Finding commits is important, though: if you can't find them, they are, in effect, gone.  Your `git push` would have changed things on the `origin` repository such that it would no longer have been able to find one of its commits, and that's why Git rejected the attempt.

A server receiving a `git push` never does a merge, even if it could.  Git doesn't know whether some merge operation is valid: `git merge` just follows simple text-substitution rules.  Someone or something else—a human, or some external testing system (such as a CI/CD system)—needs to verify the merge first.  Git puts the burden on the person or entity running `git push`, not on the server.